# Subir un archivo con multer y se quede en la pantalla actual

Tags: nodejs, express, multer

Envío un archivo al  servidor y todo bien...

Ahora lo que necesito es guardar el dato del nombre del archivo en mi base de datos y con ello saber que ya subieron el archivo indicado para poder abrir en el momento que lo deseen.

Pero como hacer que se quede en la pantalla un vez que envía el archivo y cierra la pantalla modal de donde se indican los datos del archivo a subir e invoca la ruta de envío.

Estando ya en la pantalla para modificar datos y guardar:

1. Dan clic en el botón asignado para mostrar la pantalla modal.                            (todo bien)
2. En la pantalla modal seleccionan el tipo de archivo y dan clic en aceptar para enviar el archivo al servidor y ocultar la pantalla modal.    (todo bien)
3. Dar clic en el botón asignado para guardar los cambios y cerrar la pantalla actual.                  (no he podido hacer que se quede en esta pantalla)

Este es el código del router que invoca al controlador para enviar el archivo mediante multer a la carpeta asignada.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

const uploadFileController = require('../controllers/srvUploadFile.Controller')

// Rutas para renderizar
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{  
    res.render('uploadFile')
})

router.route('/')
    .post(uploadFileController.upload, (req,res)=>{
        //console.log(req.file)
        res.send('El archivo se envió con éxito al servidor web!')
        //res.redirect('/servicios')
    })
    
module.exports = router
```

Sigo indagando porque los ejemplos que consultado todos al terminar el proceso, manda el mensaje con res.send('mensaje confirmando')

Saludos.

Ahora anexo imagen para tratar de mostrar las pantallas en cuestión..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso que quieres es asunto del frontEnd, no de  express. Debes ajustar el envío el formulario mediante javascript en el front.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que al terminar el proceso de envío del archivo  y al cierre de la pantalla modal, se mantenga en la pantalla actual (ver imagen).